# Grep specific object values in JSON array list

Tags: python, arrays, json, parsing

I have the below JSON response array list. From which the value of the jvirtualMachineId key need to be extracted for a specific service role . How can i fetch the array value of one element. for example how can i fetch the element value of jvirtualMachineId which contains analytics DB in service roles. Appreciate your help..

```
[
    {
        "dataCenterId": 1,
        "customerInstallationId": 27355,
        "addressBlockId": 535,
        "cloudHostId": 31614,
        "hostname": "-94-t-jd-am",
        "ipAddresses": [
            {
                "machineAddressId": 65097,
                "addressRangeType": "NORMAL",
                "address": "103.191.23.20"
            },
            {
                "machineAddressId": 65098,
                "addressRangeType": "NFS",
                "address": "103.191.87.20"
            }
        ],
        "machineState": "RUNNING",
        "machineType": "THUNDER",
        "standbyVirtualMachineId": -1,
        "serviceRoles": [
            "ANALYTICS_DB",
            "SBS_DB"
        ],
        "hazduPen": false,
        "jHost": {
            "cloudHostId": 31614,
            "hostName": "d.dy.com",
            "ipAddress": "103.191.23.20",
            "shortHostname": "12-25-94-ad"
        },
        "jvirtualMachineId": 32551,
        "shortHostname": "-25-94-jd-ad"
    },
    {
        "dataCenterId": 1,
        "customerInstallationId": 27355,
        "addressBlockId": 535,
        "cloudHostId": 31613,
        "hostname": "ea01fdgdf.com",
        "ipAddresses": [
            {
                "machineAddressId": 65095,
                "addressRangeType": "NORMAL",
                "address": "103.191.23.19"
            },
            {
                "machineAddressId": 65096,
                "addressRangeType": "NFS",
                "address": "103.191.87.19"
            }
        ],
        "machineState": "RUNNING",
        "machineType": "THUNDER",
        "standbyVirtualMachineId": -1,
        "serviceRoles": [
            "EAE_SERVICE"
        ],
        "hazduPen": false,
        "jHost": {
            "cloudHostId": 31613,
            "hostName": ".dynjcdfgintom",
            "ipAddress": "103.191.23.19",
            "shortHostname": "-25-94-ser"
        },
        "jvirtualMachineId": 32550,
        "shortHostname": "esrsf-ea01"
    },
    {
        "dataCenterId": 1,
        "customerInstallationId": 27355,
        "addressBlockId": 535,
        "cloudHostId": 31612,
        "hostname": "25-94-t-csom",
        "ipAddresses": [
            {
                "machineAddressId": 65093,
                "addressRangeType": "NORMAL",
                "address": "103.191.23.18"
            },
            {
                "machineAddressId": 65094,
                "addressRangeType": "NFS",
                "address": "103.191.87.18"
            }
        ],
        "machineState": "RUNNING",
        "machineType": "THUNDER",
        "standbyVirtualMachineId": -1,
        "serviceRoles": [
            "CACHE"
        ],
        "hazduPen": false,
        "jiveHost": {
            "cloudHostId": 31612,
            "hostName": "sdfsdf4-t-cs01ted.com",
            "ipAddress": "103.191.23.18",
            "shortHostname": "sdfsdf25-94-t-cs01"
        },
        "jvirtualMachineId": 32549,
        "shortHostname": "12-25-94-t-cs01"
    }
]
```

Comment: What is your programming language ???

Comment: Parse the JSON into Maps/Lists (or whatever your language supports) and navigate through that "tree".

Comment: And go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn and you'll be totally lost if you don't understand it.

Comment: how can this be Done in python

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what programming language you need to use, so I'll assume any language is OK.

Typically, if any tool will do, I try to solve simple problems with bash. Fortunately, there's a tool that makes what you've specified a simple task: [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)! Here's what you'd need to do:

```
cat data.json | jq '.[].serviceRoles="ANALYTICS_DB"|.[].jvirtualMachineId'
```

The JSON you provided isn't actually well-formed, so I've tried to read between the lines a bit: you expect an array of objects. I may have guessed wrong, in which case you'll probably need to fiddle with the `jq` accessor a bit.

Comment: OP said : 'which contains analytics DB in service roles'

Comment: It returns 3 integers

Answer (score 0):

PHP would be something like:

```
$element = what element you want to retrieve;

//fetching the file:

$jsonArray = json_decode(file_get_contents("content/coordinaten.json"));

echo 'value: '.$jsonArray[$element];

or in your specific question:

echo 'value: '.$jsonArray["jvirtualMachineId"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

```
perl -MJSON -0ne '
    my $DS = decode_json $_;
    foreach my $h (@{ $DS }) {
        print $h->{jvirtualMachineId}
            if grep { /ANALYTICS_DB/ } @{ $h->{serviceRoles} };
    }
' file.json
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
32551
```